# A sentence with "while" and "but"

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure, subordinate-clauses

I wrote:

> **While** there are cases where the context is better specified in a reverse order, **but since** the HTML structure and the content structure of most websites is top-down, this strategy can be effective in most common scenarios.

I am not sure if I used "While ..." structure correctly. Because it is almost used as "While this is true, this another thing is also true" where there is no "but" or "since"

Comment: *While...but* is not viable.  **While** works like **although**.  *There are cases where..., but since...* would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The *while* here doesn't work.  You're right in saying that it if you use *while* you need to use the structure, "while this, this also".

I'd rewrite this by simply taking the *while* out.

> There are cases where the context is better specified in a reverse order, but since the HTML structure and the content structure of most websites is top-down, this strategy can be effective in most common scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This general form of this use of "while" is:

> "While [X] (is true), also [Y] (is true)"

or

> "While [X], [Y] (is not true)"

For example:

> While he planted corn this year, he also planted soybeans.
>
> While he planted corn this year, he didn't plant alfalfa.

Here your "but" interrupts this pattern and makes it sound like you didn't complete your first thought.  So you should pick one or the other.

> He planted corn this year, but he didn't plant alfalfa.

Note that it is permissible to have a compound sentence -- even a long one -- follow "while", as long as you finish up with something that completes your thought:

> While he planted corn early in the spring, and beans later in the spring, and alfalfa in the summer, and even potatoes later in the summer, he didn't plant any okra this year.

If you want to include a counter-example, start a new sentence with "however" or a similar conjunction:

> While he planted corn, he also planted alfalfa.  However, he didn't plant okra.